# How can I use cjuiautocomplete on index.php's form?

Tags: php, database, yii, autocomplete, dropdown

I have my index.php where i am implementing searching functionality, the functionality is working, like user input some business name, and input some city name, after submit the form the business is retrieve from the database. Now my next task is to implement submission of form by using `cjuiautocomplete`. Like when user start typing the name of business, the businesses should come down in the drop down. The main hurdle in my way is that I am in index.php. I was following this http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/162/a-simple-action-for-cjuiautocomplete/ but this is for view file of a controller. How can i implement this in my index.php. Given below is my form in index.php.

```
<form action="business/searchingtesting" method="GET">                     
  <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
    <h2 class="title">Find the best places to eat, drink, shop, or visit in Islamabad. </h2>
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-md-offset-1">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="business" id="lg" placeholder="I'm looking for....">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sm" name="city"  placeholder="Islamabad">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="submit">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

If I follow the above link and use the below code in my form I get this error "undefined variable model".

```
<?php 
  $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
      'attribute' => 'my_name',
        'model' => $model,
        'sourceUrl' => array('my/aclist'),
        'name' => 'business_name',
        'options' => array(
          'minLength' => '3',
        ),
        'htmlOptions' => array(
          'size' => 45,
          'maxlength' => 45,
        ),
  )); ?>
```

Comment: give that form an ID and call the autocomplete function on it?

Comment: Are you asking me a question or what ?

Comment: Make sure you are passing `$model` variable while rendering view..

Answer (score 0):

First of all [read documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiAutoComplete). You may use CJuiAutoComplete like with model as without it. To use with model you need to specify two params: `model` and `attribute`. If you use it without model then only `name`. As I can see you doesn't use model in your form, so this example for you:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
    'name' => 'my_name',
    'sourceUrl' => array('/my/aclist'), // you need first slash if you want properly working URL from web root
));
```

Comment: Dear sir thanks for your answer, But i did it through another way.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="business/searchname" method="GET">                     
    <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
        <h2 class="title">
            Find the best places to eat, drink, shop, or visit in Islamabad. 
        </h2>
        <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-md-offset-1">
        <?php 
        $model = Business::model()->findAll();
        $modelcity = Address::model()->findAll(array(
            'select' => 't.city',
            'group' => 't.city', //selecting distinct values as many businesses hass same cities, so the drop down was filled with only one city
            'distinct' => true,
        ));

        foreach ($model as $mo) {
            $store[] = $mo->business_name;
        }
        foreach ($modelcity as $c) {
            $city[] = $c->city;
        }

        $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
            'name' => 'business',
            'source' => array_values($store),
            // additional javascript options for the autocomplete plugin
            'options' => array(
            'minLength' => '2',
        ),
        'htmlOptions' => array(
            'style' => 'height:45px;width:415px;',
            'placeholder' => '          I am Looking for................ ',
        ),
        ));?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <?php 
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
            'name' => 'city',
            'source' => array_values($city),
            // additional javascript options for the autocomplete plugin
            'options' => array(
                'minLength' => '2',
            ),
            'htmlOptions' => array(
                'style' => 'height:45px; width:250px;',
                'placeholder'=>'          City................ ',
            ),
        ));
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="submit"/>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```